# Keep column height in Beamer when replacing content

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, columns

I have a frame in Beamer that consists of two columns.  The content of one column remains the same, the content of the other column is replaced on the second slide.

```
\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
      % some static content
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
      \begin{onlyenv}<1>
        % some tikz picture
      \end{onlyenv}
      \begin{onlyenv}<2>
        % some other tikz picture
      \end{onlyenv}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

The problem with this configuration is that since the height of the second column changes, the position of the content of the first column also changes, and so the transition between the slides is not smooth - The first column "jumps" around.

How can I keep the first column static, while changing the seconds?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does the `overprint` environment do what you want? You'd place it around both of your `onlyenv` environments. It reserves a common block of space for the pictures so that all versions of the slide "see" the same size box in the second column (regardless of the actual size of the picture), which should get rid of the "jumping".

See also the `overlayarea` environment, which gives you more control; both of these are documented in section 9.5 of the `beamer` manual.

Comment: Using the `overprint` environment you're required to use the `\onslide<...>` overlay specification (`onlyenv` doesn't produce consistent results in my small tests). Alternatively, `overlayarea` would work just as well without the above restriction.

Comment: Thanks for the refs! These environments do keep the second column in place.  I also found that minipages does a similar thing.