# Changing figure position in a two-column presentation slide

Tags: beamer, floats, positioning

I am trying to make a presentation with the `beamer` package. One of the slides requires me to have an image change with every new line of text I open.

I do this by splitting the slide in columns with `column` environment, putting the text in an `item` environment in the left column, and... trying out various things for the images.

My current slides are using `\only<x>{ .. }`, and I am aware this is most likely the problem. But, I've tried tips from all the similar questions ([this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31946/keep-column-height-in-beamer-when-replacing-content), [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44630/beamer-only-with-columns-makes-things-move-down), [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148/avoiding-jumping-frames-in-beamer), [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17992/2975)), but using `\onslide` (with or without `overlay` or `overprint` environment) jams all the images together and does not transition through them at all.

I've checked that my images are of the completely same size (it's 3-steps-of-a-process, the same image with new elements in each step), but they still keep changing position. The latex code I am using right now:

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item<1-> \emph{Important text}
        \item<2-> Very important process
            \begin{itemize}
                    \item<3-> Steps one and two
                    \item<5-> Step with no image
            \end{itemize}
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
    \vspace{0cm}
        \begin{figure}[h]
        \only<2>{ \includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{img/proc0.png} }
        \only<3>{ \includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{img/proc1.png} }
        \only<4>{ \includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{img/proc2.png} }
        \end{figure}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

My taughts were that the `figure` environment might reserve the space that `\only<x>` does not... and it *helped a little* but not all the way. Without the `figure` environment, `proc1.png` is displayed a little to the right of `proc0.png`, and `proc2.png` is displayed a little more to the right. With the `figure` environment, `proc1.png` is again displayed a bit more to the right than `proc0.png`, but then `proc2.png` is displayed in the same place.

I've tried all the combinations I have found on Google and here that made sense to me. Currently, I ran out of inspiration for what else to try so I would appreciate any help from the community.

Here are the images I am using (if you guys think they are too big to be in a post, I will just change it into a link, but for now..):

[image: Image1] [image: Image2]
[image: Image3]

Comment: You don't need to add `figure` around `\includegraphics`. It works fine on its own as long you don't want a caption.

Comment: @MartinScharrer I just tried removing the `figure` environment to re-check. There is a difference, I edited my post and now there is a passage under the latex-code explaining the different behaviors with/without `figure`

Comment: I didn't meant removing `figure` would solve it, just that it is not required in this case anyway.

Comment: Please also check [Dancing images in beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17992/2975).

Comment: @MartinScharrer I did check and try out that link, that's where I got the \vspace{0cm} from. I just couldn't find all the questions I checked while I was writing the question. Also, since with the `figure` environment I got a bit more desirable results than without it, it was in my last-used latex-code that I posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item<1-> \emph{Important text}
        \item<2-> Very important process
            \begin{itemize}
                    \item<3-> Steps one and two
                    \item<5-> Step with no image
            \end{itemize}
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
        \begin{overlayarea}{0.38\textwidth}{4cm}
        \includegraphics<2>[scale = 0.6]{proc0.png}%
        \includegraphics<3>[scale = 0.6]{proc1.png}%
        \includegraphics<4>[scale = 0.6]{proc2.png}%
        \end{overlayarea}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would use `\includegraphics<2>[scale = 0.6]{proc0.png}` etc. instead. The problem might be spurious spaces after the `}`. Adding `%` there might also be a good idea.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Indeed I was just copy/pasting from the OP's code. Let me fix that

Comment: @percusse sorry for being a newbie, what does `%` do exactly? otherwise, works perfectly :) great

Comment: @penelope No problem. It is the commenting out character and TeX ignores anything that comes after that on the same line. This makes sure that there is no accidental horizontal space typeset.

Comment: @percusse. I knew about the comment character, just not about how it could be used in the same way. Could you maybe edit than in the answer as a short explanation, so we don't pollute the comment section? I think it's relevant and useful...