# Changing the colour of a smartdiagram in beamer

Tags: beamer, smartdiagram

I have built a beamer presentation utilising the smartdiagram package.

The diagram appears animated but then I want to highlight two of the steps on the smart diagram. I have done this with the following code but is there a way to do it within a single frame? I have looked at using the \againframe command but had no success. The code below generates the desired effect but on 3 frames rather than 1.

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{Boadilla}
    \usecolortheme{seahorse}
    \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}

\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Slide Title}
    \centering
    \scalebox{0.6}{
        \smartdiagramset{sequence item height=2.5cm,
        uniform color list=gray!60 for 5 items,
        }
        \smartdiagramanimated[sequence diagram]{Step 1, Step 2, Step 3, Step 4, Step 5
        }
    }
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Slide Title} % Highlight the 1st item red
    \centering
    \scalebox{0.6}{
        \smartdiagramset{sequence item height=2.5cm, set color list={red!60,gray!60,gray!60,gray!60,gray!60}
        }
        \smartdiagram[sequence diagram]{Step 1, Step 2, Step 3, Step 4, Step 5
        }
    }
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Slide Title} % highglight the 1st and 4th item red
    \centering
    \scalebox{0.6}{
        \smartdiagramset{sequence item height=2.5cm,
    set color list={red!60,gray!60,gray!60,red!60,gray!60}
        }
        \smartdiagram[sequence diagram]{Step 1, Step 2, Step 3, Step 4, Step 5
        }
    }
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You can use `onlyenv`, see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31946/keep-column-height-in-beamer-when-replacing-content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. All you need is to add the custom color list from slides 6 onwards, which can be achieved with

```
\only<6>{\smartdiagramset{set color
        list={red!60,gray!60,gray!60,gray!60,gray!60}}}
```

and so on. Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{Boadilla}
    \usecolortheme{seahorse}
    \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}

\usepackage{smartdiagram}
%\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Slide Title}
    \centering
    \scalebox{0.6}{
        \smartdiagramset{sequence item height=2.5cm,
        uniform color list=gray!60 for 5 items}
        \only<6>{\smartdiagramset{set color
        list={red!60,gray!60,gray!60,gray!60,gray!60}}}
        \only<7>{\smartdiagramset{set color
        list={red!60,gray!60,gray!60,red!60,gray!60}}}
        \smartdiagramanimated[sequence diagram]{Step 1, Step 2, Step 3, Step 4, Step 5
        }
    }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much!

I also used the '\againframe<6>' command to call the highlighted image at a later point

Comment: @PhilipAldhous Yes, `\againframe` is certainly useful. You may also want to have a look at the Ti*k*Z library `overlay-beamer-styles`, which is by the same author as `smartdiagram` and another tool that can be used to avoid repetition, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/488106/121799.